# Appliying patch in drupal modules

Tags: linux, drupal, patch

I have an installed drupal module : revioning. 
To add some functionalities, someone submit a patch file in drupal site here:

http://drupal.org/node/938074

My question is how to apply patches???

My server is linux centos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have shell access to the server then cd to the module directory, download the patch file (e.g. `wget http://drupal.org/files/issues/file.patch`) and then run the command:

```
patch -p1 < file.patch
```

(replacing file.patch with the name of the patch file you've just downloaded)

There's a lot more information on applying patches here: http://drupal.org/patch/apply